# c++/cli DLL openFileDialog freeze and block the Test aplication

Tags: dll, c++-cli

I have a strange problem ...

I have implement the following fonction

```
private:
   void button1_Click( Object^ /*sender*/, System::EventArgs^ /*e*/ )
   {
      Stream^ myStream;
      OpenFileDialog^ openFileDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog;
      openFileDialog1->Filter = (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
      openFileDialog1->FilterIndex = 2;
      openFileDialog1->RestoreDirectory = true;

      if ( openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK )
      {
         if ( (myStream = openFileDialog1->OpenFile()) != nullptr )
         {
            // her is my listview code
            myStream->Close();
         }
      }
   }
```

in my DLL:

my problem is that, when testing the code as dll, the dialog is not displayed but freezes the application Completely and may be terminated only by Task Manager ...no idea what was going on there ... gives no sense to me. who can help me please?

Comment: I think more information would help. What does the call stack look like at the point of the 'ShowDialog' call? Perhaps there is something preventing the dialog from processing events.

Answer (score 0):

In the .NET Framework version 2.0, you can also specify the COM threading model for a C++ application using the /CLRTHREADATTRIBUTE (Set CLR Thread Attribute) linker option.

VS Setting:STA threading attribute (/CLRTHREADATTRIBUTE:STA)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.stathreadattribute%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score -1):

```
openFileDialog1->ShowHelp = true;
```

I put this line then it solved the problem.